# Many table view cell got created

Tags: ios, swift, instruments

I am using swift UITableView. In viewDidLoad method, I registered a customized table view cell as below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "QuestionTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "askCell")
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I reuse the cell as below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("askCell") as! QuestionTableViewCell
```

When I scroll the table I see that there are many table cell instances got created as show below. I wander if I use reusable cell, how many cells should be created.

[image]

Comment: You create as many cell as the value which returns from your `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Comment: @GiovanniGrano That is not true

Comment: The number of cells that should be created would be that fit the screen + 1 or 2 i think.Not more than that

Comment: How many cells are on the screen at once? Is `prepareForReuse()` called in your cell subclass? Do you get the same behavior if you use `dequeueReusableCell(identifier:for:)` instead of `dequeueReusableCell(identifier:)`?

Comment: There will be 3 to 5 cells on the screen at once, since the cell has different height. Why did I get so many cells in the instrument?

Comment: @AaronBrager I didn't call prepareForReuse(). And I didn't see any different with dequeueReusableCell you mentioned

Comment: Please check prepareForReuse().

Comment: Perhaps you have a retain cycle?